# LINQ Union not returning wanted results

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, union

I have problem I've been trying to solve for the last couple of hours but without any luck at all.

First, let me show you how my database looks like (just an important part of it):
[image]

[radno_mjesto] = JOB
[grupa_radnih_mjesta] = JOB GROUPS (jobs that fall into specific groups; for example if the group name was **judges** jobs that would fall into this group would be: **supreme court judge**, **administrative law judge**, **senior judge**, etc.)
[osoba] = PERSON

What I'd like to achieve is to query all the people who fall into specific job groups, but after couple of hours I wasn't able to succeed in doing it so. I was trying various combinations of the following code and there are only 2 results I've been getting: all people (no matter what their job is) or people with specific job only (the last job from the job group as in this case).

```
        var sveOsobe = from p in db.osobas
                       select p;


        if (chkGrupaRadnihMjesta.Checked)
        {
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(GrupaRadnihMjesta.SelectedValue);

            var radnaMjesta = from rm in db.grupe_radnih_mjesta_radna_mjesta
                              where rm.grm_id == id
                              select rm;

            var praznoOsobe = sveOsobe.Where(o => o.osoba_id == -1);

            foreach (var radnoMjesto in radnaMjesta)
            {
                var sveOsobeRadnaMjesta = from p in db.osobas
                                          where p.osoba_id == -1
                                          select p;

                sveOsobeRadnaMjesta = sveOsobe.Where(o => o.rm_id == radnoMjesto.rm_id).Union(sveOsobeRadnaMjesta);
                praznoOsobe = praznoOsobe.Union(sveOsobeRadnaMjesta);
            }
            sveOsobe = sveOsobe.Intersect(praznoOsobe);
        }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It is not your fault but the names are hard to remember for a person not familiar with your language. It looks like a substitution cipher has been applied. Maybe you can translate them?

Comment: You know you don't need to use the same exact names in your LINQ contexts that are used in the databases, you can give tables and columns _meaningful_ names and still map to the obfuscated names.  Do yourself (and us) a favor and do that. It is terribly difficult to even understand what your code is doing.

Comment: Actually, this project is something that I had inherited from a third person. Personally, I do use shorter table names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work....

```
if (chkGrupaRadnihMjesta.Checked) { 
  int id = Convert.ToInt32(GrupaRadnihMjesta.SelectedValue); 
  var sveOsobe = (
    from p in db.osobas 
    join l in db.grupe_radnih_mjesta_radna_mjesta on l.rm_id equals p.rm_id
    where l.grm_id == id
    select p
  ).Distinct();
}
```

I'm guessing at names here!!!

Comment: Thank you, that was the solution!